# PCB Single Local Fiducial

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly, fiducial

I have a question regarding local fiducials so as to achieve proper alignment of the board, during the soldering of a 0.4mm pitch chip. As I have seen the best practice for local fiducials is to place 2 of them, one on the upper right corner of the chip and one down and left. Due to lack of space I can only place one fiducial at the down left corner. Is this going to be helpful or useless? I have also placed 3 global fiducials for general board alignment.

Thank you

Comment: The only person who can answer definitively is your fabricator, but to me it seems like one local and 3 more should be fine.

Comment: Where I worked we had in-house SMT fab.  We used three global fiducials out near the corners, and one local one dead center in the footprint of the occasional fine-pitch part (TQFP, etc.).  The robots had cameras and AOI to check the rotation and offset after picking, and make adjustments before placement.

Comment: A single local fiducial will not really gain you anything more than only relying on the three global fiducials.